# There is a circular table with $10$ seating , we want to place $6$ people to this circular table.How many ways are there?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, permutations, polya-counting-theory

> There is a circular table with $10$ seating , we want to place $6$ people to this circular table.How many ways are there ?

**My try:** I thought the empty seats as identical object that will be placed by $6$ distinct object (i.e $6$ people) , so my answer is $$\frac{(10-1)!}{4!}=15,120$$

**IS MY SOLUTION CORRECT ?**

**Secondly**  , i want to learn how to solve this problem using $\color{red}{\text{polya counting method}}$  such that "How many possible way are there arrange $6$ distinct and $4$ identical object in

a-) circular table (i.e $2-D$)

b-) necklace (i.e, $3-D$ )

**IMPORTANT NOTE :** @user2661923 corrected my answer , but my main purpose is to see application of Polya theorem in this question . I mentioned my this aim in "Secondly" part. Hence , i am waiting for the solutions of part "a" and "b". Thanks in advance !

Comment: Why did you subtract 1 from the number of seats?

Comment: @Kuhlambo See the comments following my answer.

Comment: To the OP (i.e. original poster) : Polya Theory is a somewhat involved topic.  I recommend attacking it by finding reference(s) that you are comfortable with.  I very briefly attacked it by googling : "group theory polya counting method pdf".  One reference that I like is [this one](http://www.geometer.org/mathcircles/polya.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

I am ignorant of Polya Theory and I came up with the same answer by a different approach.

With one of the people arbitrarily designated as the *head of the table* (AKA the *twelve-oclock position*), the remaining $(5)$ people can be permuted in $(5!)$ ways.

Then, the $(6)$ regions of (potentially) empty spaces (between the people) can be filled by the number of non-negative integer solutions to

$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 = 4 ~: ~\binom{9}{5} ~\text{solutions.} \tag1 $$

$\displaystyle (5!) \times \binom{9}{5}~$ agrees with your computation.

See also
[this Stars and Bars article](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/) and
[this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

---

**Edit**
It could be argued that Polya Theory would *become necessary* for the following related problem:

Suppose that you have $(6)$ groups of identical triplets ($18$ people).  Further suppose that you are seating them at a circular table with $(30)$ chairs.  Further suppose that each set of triplets is to be regarded as indistinguishable from each other, but distinguishable from the other $(15)$ people, with respect to enumerating distinct seating arrangements.

Then, how many rotationally distinct ways are there of seating the $(18)$ people around the table?

Comment: Where do you get the head of the table from?

Comment: @Kuhlambo Since the table is circular, any seating can be *rotated* so that an arbitrary person is in the *twelve-oclock* position, which I am loosely referring to as the *head-of-the-table*.

Comment: I don't see it, the answer is for 5 people on 9 seats, that is not the question is it?

Comment: @Kuhlambo The question is for $(10)$ people around a circular table.  Suppose that the people are named A,B,C,D,E,F.  Seat person A.  Now, since the table is circular, rather than straight, all seating assignments may be viewed from the perspective of person A.  For example, suppose that you number the seats $(1)$ through $(10)$.  Further suppose that seats $(1)$ through $(6)$ are occupied by A,B,C,D,E,F, respectively, with seats $(7)$ through $(10)$ empty.   ...see next comment

Comment: @Kuhlambo Because the table is circular, this is regarded as the same seating as if B,C,D,E,F were placed in seats $(1)$ through $(5)$ and A was placed in seat $(10)$.

Comment: Okay that was impossible to get from the question. But i guess that's how it is sometimes if you know the field you already know the answer before the student even gets the question...

Comment: @Kuhlambo Yes, the only alternative way that you could know this is by knowing about the general convention that when a Math problem involves enumerating distinct seatings around a  circular table, the problem composer intends *rotationally distinct* rather than *linearly distinct* seatings.  This is the *relevance* of specifying that the table is circular.

Comment: @user2661923 see edition

Comment: @GeneralCarl I didn't *correct* your answer.  Instead, my computation agrees with yours.  So, while I am unfamiliar with the analysis you used, I suspect that your analysis is valid, because otherwise it would be very coincidental.  As I indicated, I am generally ignorant of Polya Theory, so I can't really give you the specific analysis that you are asking for.  Further, as I indicated in my comment following your question, an alternative approach, in case no one else steps up, is for you to self-research the pertinent online references.

Comment: @user2661923 why do you suspect that my analysis is valid ? It is simple , lets say we have four temporary people say $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4$. They sit with other $6$ people by $9!$ ways , after sitting , we request them to leave their sitting .Because of that  , divide by $4!$

Comment: @GeneralCarl Yes, that makes sense, and is a more elegant  approach than the one that I took.  I simply didn't think of it.